# Externalize springboot component in PCF manifest.yaml

Tags: spring-boot, cloud-foundry

I want to deploy springboot app with externalize springboot component on PCF .

Is it possible to add following in manifest.yaml  ?

```
  java -cp 
 -Dloader.main=com.khan.vaquar.JdbcFullApp
 -Dloader.path= org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher
```

Comment: You can add additional system properties to your Java app by setting them through JAVA_OPTS. Ex: `cf set-env my-application JAVA_OPTS '<stuff to add>'`. I think that should at least work for your example above. Oh, you can put those in manifest.yml in the `env` block too.

Comment: You mean to say i can set variable on pcf using this command                         cf   set-env my-application JAVA_OPTS -Dloader.main=org.thingsboard.server.ThingsboardInstallApplication \
                        -Dinstall.load_demo=${loadDemo} \
                        -Dspring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none \
                        -Dinstall.upgrade=false \
                        -Dlogging.config=/usr/share/thingsboard/bin/install/logback.xml \
                        org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher

Comment: Yes. The Java buildpack will incorporate the full contents of `JAVA_OPTS` into the start command that it generates so whatever JVM arguments you add to that env variable will end up in the start command generated by the JBP.